# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method

Tags: c#, linq

I checked online for some answers, and I understood that I cannot translate ToInt32 to T-SQL, and I need to use run my query in-memory first and then do the conversion, but I don't know how to apply it in my example. I have the query below, and it shows me the error message written in the title:

```
string[] parts = rvm.ZipCode.Split('-');
var list = results.OrderBy(b => 
  Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]) - Convert.ToInt32(b.Zip))).Take(5).ToList();
```

Where `results` is another query that I applied earlier. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: From what I understand, you need to convert it to int32 in a local variable *first*, and then feed it to your LINQ query.    Which makes me wonder if you wrap the whole convert part in parenthesis, would the compiler process that first?   Worth a shot.  If not, just make a local variable of the int32, and feed that to LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// It would be better, if we make the conversion only once instead of 
// doing this each time we fetch an item from our collection.
int value = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);

var list = results.AsEnumerable()
                  .OrderBy(z => Math.Abs(value - Convert.ToInt32(z.Zip)))
                  .Take(5)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `AsEnumerable()` will force it to do the ordering in memory:

```
var list = results.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(b => Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]) - Convert.ToInt32(b.Zip))).Take(5).ToList();
```

This may be extremely ineficient though as the `Take(5)` will occur after the data has already been retrieved from the database, so you are fetching the entire result set into memory, sorting it an then discarding all but the top 5 records.

Answer (score 0):

Linq2SQL and Linq2Entity always try and pass the query to the database and most databases don't have the same functionality as the convert class. this means that to apply the convert function you need to instruct linq to retrieve the data from the database so that it can run the code rather than just passing it to the database.

this is done by instantiating the query by calling AsEnumerable() or ToList() **before** you call the convert function

the other option would be to change it to a simpler convert such as (int) or as int? as these do have a direct database mapping