# How do I convert string to integer inside select new statement in LINQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my query...

```
var salesSelection = (from a in crmDBContext.Quotes
                      where a.quoteDate >= startDate && a.quoteDate <= endDate && a.region == regionselect
                      group a by new { a.customerNumber } into queryOut
                      select new { queryOut.Key.customerNumber,
                      totalQuantity = queryOut.Sum(q => int.Parse(q.itemQuantity)),
                      totalPrice = queryOut.Sum(s => s.price) }).OrderByDescending(i => i.totalPrice);
```

I get an error that linq doesn't recognize the method. 
I have also tried 
`totalQuantity = queryOut.Sum(q => Convert.ToInt32(q.itemQuantity))`.

I am not allowed to change the actual column in the table in the database to reflect the quantity as an integer instead of a string as the table updates daily from our mainframe.

Is there a way to do this conversion inside of the linq query, and if not, is there a way to retrieve all of the quantities and sum them later without having to requery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299763/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-toint32system-string-me)

Comment: The accepted answer for that question doesn't work for my problem. I still get the same error. I can't get the results and then take the sum from the results because the results will only return one quantity, the first or the last.